# where the traffic control(TC) module save it's statistic data？Which path

Tags: linux

for example：

```
sudo tc -s class show dev ens9f0 
class htb 1:22 parent 1:2 prio 0 rate 15Gbit ceil 20Gbit burst 0b cburst 0b 
 Sent 5060059585301 bytes 563925789 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 86000741 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 lended: 79948165 borrowed: 6052610 giants: 0
 tokens: -1 ctokens: -1
```

I want to know where the statistic data（Sent 5060059585301） stored？
thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistics are kept in kernel's memory; they're not saved anywhere else, and are lost on reboot.

The `tc` and `ip` tools retrieve statistics from the kernel via [Netlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) (the same system that they use to submit configuration – e.g. when you create a new queue, tc sends a Netlink command).

If you only want to automate statistics retrieval in some convenient format, try the `-j` option for JSON output (e.g. `tc -j -s class show`).